# odoo widget HTML content cleared when click save button

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I'm using odoo 9.0 community version:

```html
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="jjbbs.list_form">
  <field name="name">BBS</field>
  <field name="model">jjbbs.jjbbs</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
     <sheet string="BBS">
    <form>

        <h2><field name="name" string="title"   placeholder="title"  /></h2>

        <field name="catagory" placeholder="catagory" String="catagory"/>
            <field String="Content" name="content" widget="html"/>

    </form>
  </sheet>


     <sheet string="replies">
    <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers"/>
    <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
  </sheet>

 </field>
</record>
```

This is my odoo view for form,
but every time I click the save button to save the content I have changed, the content will be cleared.

Comment: updated to the latest version .issue resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upgraded to the latest version ,this issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a form view. You're using search tags. I don't know if there are errors on the backend side, but this view should be

```html
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="jjbbs.searchview">
  <field name="name">workreport.search</field>
  <field name="model">workreport.workreport</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form>
        <field name="content" String="Content"/>
        <field name="create_uid" String="User"/>
    </form>
  </field>
</record>
```

Comment: sorry , I posted the wrong code, I did use form view

Comment: Then the order of sheet and form seems to be inverted. And you could add the python code you're using. I think that it does have nothing to do with views.

Comment: there is no custom python code added, if I remove  widget="html" ,this issue  will be resolved, but I do need RTF text area